# Why can i use the short name with some permissions / scopes on microsoft identity platform AAD v 2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect, microsoft-identity-platform

When setting up my OAuth client app, i need to define scopes.  I know of the built in scopes for things like open id connect such as `openid` `profile` `email` etc, and according to docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#scopes-and-permissions

> Identity platform supports several well-defined OpenID Connect scopes as well as resource-based permissions (each permission is indicated by appending the permission value to the resource's identifier or application ID URI). For example, the permission string https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read is used to request permission to read users calendars in Microsoft Graph.

but in practice i find that most docs (even that same doc later on) often use "short names" for graph scopes, like User.Read.All  cf https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#admin-restricted-permissions:

> Read all user's full profiles by using `User.Read.All`

What's going on here, are the MS apis special and have special short name aliases for their permissions/scopes?  Is this doc'd anywhere to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Microsoft Identity platform will assume that you were referring to Microsoft Graph if you omit the resource in the scope value. Thus, `User.Read` is treated as `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read`.

Comment: is this doc'd anywhere?

Comment: It's documented in various places where it's used (e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-acquire-cache-tokens#request-scopes-for-a-web-api)), but surprisingly not (yet) in [the main article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent) where we'd expect it. I've submitted an update with this note, you can expect it to be published in the next few hours.